# ionic 2 tabs in all pages (including new pages)

Tags: angular, tabs, ionic2

I'm new to ionic2 and i want to create a shopping app that have both sidemenu layout for app navigation(categories,deals,settings,login,viewaccount,etc...). And 3 tabs (home,wishlist,cart), I have started new project based on tabs layout and managed to add sidemenu.

How i can keep the 3 tabs available for all existing pages including new pages that i want to create in the future? I want the tabs to be fixed for all pages and for the user to navigate to any of the tabs at anytime inside any page. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

download conference app from github.

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app

You get every thing from there as per your requirement.

Comment: Best answer so far, i didn't see any blog articles or answers about this subject. You saved my day ;).

Answer (score 0):

You should use "tabs" of ionic 2 than "segments". As tabs are set as root of the navigation stack.

For tabs, refer [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#tabs).

Or you might have to manually implement "segments" on all pages of the app.

For segments, refer [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#segment).