# Ionic 3 Tabs for each and every pages in a project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using Ionic3 for developing my hybrid application. now I stuck with an issue because in my project I want to fix tabs for each and every page for this I referred many sites

[SITE 1](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/show-tabs-menu-bar-in-all-page-if-click-on-side-menu-then-tabs-menu-bar-is-not-visible-in-all-pages/101242)

[SITE 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41848270/ionic-2-tabs-in-all-pages-including-new-pages)

but unfortunately, I don't find any solution for this problem.

Comment: How are you navigating through pages, setRoot or push?

Comment: As @PradnyaSinalkar is probably implying as well, the `Tabs` are the root of your navigation stack. So when you call `navCtrl.setRoot(SomePage)` your tabs will be lost. If you use `navCtrl.push(SomePage)` you add the page to the navigation stack, keeping the tabs. (Also, using `.setRoot` doesn't make sense when you want to keep tabs on the page)

Comment: You can try tabsHideOnSubPages option for Tabs Configuration. Is that set in your app.module.ts? Can refer ionicframework.com/docs/api/config/Config

Comment: Thanks, for the solution. I'm trying to fix the problem as you said

Comment: @PradnyaSinalkar as you said I included 'IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,{tabsHideOnSubPages: true})' in app.module.ts but it doesn't works

Comment: @balakrishnan, I solved this query for hiding tabs on pages, for you maybe solution will be opposite. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Page1" tabsHideOnSubPages="false"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Page2" tabsHideOnSubPages="false"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Page3" tabsHideOnSubPages="false"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: thanks, @Pradnya I tried your code but it was not working I achieved it by using footer instead of tabs and it was working properly! So footer is the only way to achieve this!